# spring 3.0.5-RELEASE and javaconfig

Tags: spring, maven

what is the correct maven dependency for spring 3.0.5-RELEASE and the javaconfig features (@Configuration, @Bean, etc.)?

I tried this: 
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.javaconfig/spring-javaconfig

But I got the error described here:
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=74730

That thread seems to imply that javaconfig is bundled with spring 3, but when I remove the explicit spring-javaconfig dependency (1.0.0.m3) it can't find the symbols.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple...

Answer (score 0):

JavaConfig is part of core Spring as of Spring 3.0.   So you just need to have a dependency on `spring-context`.

Comment: I ended up ditching the JavaConfig at the moment, so I'm not pressed for any answer, but what is the full package path to @Configuration? Has it changed from pre-spring-3.0?

Comment: org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration.   See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html

Comment: I guess @AnnotationDrivenTx is only supported in javaconfig, not in spring3.0:(